# Word VBA:Extract tables from selection

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a selection in a word document which I set with

`With Selection.Find 

.Text = "Blala"

        .Forward = True

        .Wrap = wdFindContinue

       .MatchCase = True

    End With

    Selection.Find.Execute

    Selection.Extend

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find

       .Text = "Tada"

        .Forward = True

        .Wrap = wdFindStop

       .MatchCase = True

    End With

    Selection.Find.Execute`

But in that selection there are also tables, I only want to format text. Is there a way to exclude the tables from that selection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code loops through all paragraphs within the selection and only performs the replacement of "Blala" with "Tada" if there are no tables in that paragraph:

```
Sub ReplaceTextButSkipTables()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim p As Paragraph

    Set rng = Selection.Range
    For Each p In rng.Paragraphs
        If p.Range.Tables.Count = 0 Then
            With p.Range.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .MatchCase = True
                With .Replacement
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = InchesToPoints(1.27)
                End With
                .Execute FindText:="Blala", ReplaceWith:="Tada", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        End If
    Next p

End Sub
```

Comment: That looks good, I suppose if I want to do sth else (not the replacement) then I add it after the .Execute part.

Comment: What is it that you want to do?

Comment: I need to change the Inches to Points stuff 
 With Selection.ParagraphFormat
.LeftIndent = InchesToPoints(1.27)

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing anything wrong, but it's still formatting the text inside the table, I'd like the tables to be completely untouched.

Comment: The ``ClearFormatting`` may not do what you think ;)  It resets the Find/Replace formatting to "no change". I've updated the code to set the ``LeftIndent`` to InchesToPoints(1.27).